# Best way in Angular 6 to check that a scrollable area is scrolled max bottom

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I try to find a good working solution for angular 6 to check the scrollable host component that its max scrolled bottom or not.

I cant find any working example for a function that checks if a custom scrollable container (like a div or what ever) is `max bottom` scrolled or not. I found something about `IntersectionObserver` but i think this is not that what i need. Tryed also couple of vanilla JS functions, but maybe i just dont have the skills to make them work in angular.

Here a Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mark6-messenger

Please keep in mind that i need this for a open Source Project. The `<ng-container` is in my ase the scrollable container: https://github.com/DevMonkeysDE/ngx-mark6/blob/master/projects/mark6-lib/src/lib/messenger/messenger-history.html#L1

It must work without that people need to add later on the coponent any `functions`, `ids` or something else. The logic must work component inside.

Answer (score 4):

Finally figured out your issue... But I did it with pure JavaScript which is working fine for me. I checked in your code. Please do the below changes and do let me know is that you was looking for.

**1. site-messanger.component.ts**

```
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event']) 
        public scrollHandler(event) {
         let obj = document.getElementById('markMessageHistory');
         let objScrollHeight = Math.round((obj.scrollTop) * 100) / 100;
        if ( (objScrollHeight) === (obj.scrollHeight - obj.offsetHeight - 0.55)) {
                console.log('object to bottom');
            }
    }
```

**2. site-messanger.template.html**

```
<mark6-messenger-history id="markMessageHistory" (scroll)="scrollHandler($event)">
                    <mark6-messenger-message [messages]="messages" [avatarMe]="false" [avatarOthers]="true"></mark6-messenger-message>
                </mark6-messenger-history>
```

I have added id to your component. Now if I scroll your component till bottom it will show me console log that your component is at bottom.

***Note -*** The 0.55 is added by considering your margin.

Comment: I Add variables and output it with: `{{test}}` in the HTML File. But the Variable is not changing when i scroll down.
````
@HostListener('window:scroll', [])
onScroll(): void {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) === document.body.scrollHeight) {
    this.test = true;
} else {
    this.test = false;
}
}    @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
onScroll(): void {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) === document.body.scrollHeight) {
    this.test = true;
} else {
    this.test = false;
}
}
````

Comment: I have updated my answer... Can you please check once?

Comment: Thanks, but now i just tryed your code with a console log inside the if... but i dont get any console log when i scroll down. Check in my first comment my code. the requirement was a variable that change his status in realtime to true when content is scrolled bottom :) and just after 1 px scrolled top direct to false.

Comment: It would be great if you could upload your code to 
 [1]: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4xy3bz

Comment: Okay thats strange: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flsdp2 here it works... But check please this File: https://github.com/DevMonkeysDE/ngx-mark6/blob/master/projects/mark6-lib/src/lib/messenger/messenger.ts#L37

Its exactly the same code but in my project it dont work. If you want you can check the whole repository out and navigate after `ng serve` to /messenger to check it local

Comment: I think the problem is that we work with window.scroll. we need to check the end of scrolling of a single div container. It works only when we use your code on a element that have the full browser height.

Comment: I also updated my stackbliz. The Red area is the scrollable content area. Now in this case the examplecode from you dont work :)

Comment: I have updated my answer.. Requesting you to please check once.

Comment: Thanks alot, but i get javascript errors with this code example when i scroll: `Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of null`. And its a problem when i need to ad somewhere the height of the textarea, because the textarea grows on input. and what is if someone who ise it, overwrite my css to change margins and bottoms? :) I am so sorry to telling you that, but i need any 100% dynamic solution for this.

Comment: This might be because your HostListener code is in different place but I added hostlistener in same component.ts file.

Comment: Ah its because i tryed to add ` id="markMessageHistory" (scroll)="scrollHandler($event)"`` to the `<ng-content select="mark6-messenger-message"></ng-content>` Thats ofc not possible. We must bind it to the `host` element and make it work without : ` id="markMessageHistory" (scroll)="scrollHandler($event)"` Check my repository. The logic is not as you titled in `1. site-messanger.component.ts` Its in `messenger.ts` and the component is used in `site-messenger.html` The logic is not available there. And i cant force people who use this package to add ids or onscroll functions :)